# OperationalError while connecting django and mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a problem connecting the mysql database with django. I have already tried to find solutions on the internet but nothing helped me. When I change the code in the 'setting.py' file and then enter 'python manage.py migrate' in the console:

```
(blog) PS C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\blog> python manage.py migrate                                                   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 166, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2059, <NULL>)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 387, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 64, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\database.py", line 10, in check_database_backends
    issues.extend(conn.validation.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 9, in check
    issues.extend(self._check_sql_mode(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 13, in _check_sql_mode
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 233, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 217, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
    return Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\Dev\blog\blog\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 166, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2059, <NULL>)
```

It's frustrating because I can't fix it and I'm just starting to learn Django. Thank you in advance for your help.

My Database code from 'setting.py':

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'blog',
        'USER': 'Shiraga',
        'PASSWORD': 'MYPASSWORD',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your database for permissions, log into MySQL and run

`GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';`

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Please do post what your Django settings.py contains.

Comment: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` is not required with `GRANT ... `

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific, please

Comment: When i use GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'Shiraga'@'localhost';; with my name user i have error :Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'Shiraga'@'%' (using password: YES) 0.000 sec
And i add database from 'setting.py' up

Comment: Seems like the user 'Shiraga' does not exist in the database.
`mysql -u nonexistant -psekret -h localhost`
Try running this command.

Comment: Your issue is not with django, its just a mysql error as the user does not exist already if not create a new user and use that in your config file to connect to.

Comment: But when I worked with Python without django, I could work on tables and create them using exactly the same user. I used this command in cmd and powershell but it doesn't recognize the command.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I was able to fix the problem after a long fight. I solved it by switching from Python 3.8 to 3.7.5. Previous to 3.8 when installing mysqlclient via 'pip install mysqlclient' an error occurred and I was forced to download a file from the site. In version 3.7.5 with renewal of the created environment this problem did not occur and the migration was successful.